# what is wrong with this layout, double clicks

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I was trying to do something similar to this app List

[image]

But this was too hard for me, I can't understand very well the layout system, so I ended up doing something in RecyclerView with rectangular and imagebuttons in the left and two on the right. All buttons will have some functions. If you click the star it will add/remove it from favorites, the download button will download it, and the right buttons are to delete and update.

[image]

I added the function for clickListener using this code from google

```
public class RecyclerItemClickListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }

    GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

    public RecyclerItemClickListener(Context context, OnItemClickListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent e) {
        View childView = view.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (childView != null && mListener != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
            mListener.onItemClick(childView, view.getChildPosition(childView));
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    }
}
```

and linked the Listener doing this:

```
 mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(
                new RecyclerItemClickListener(this, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                        Context context = getApplicationContext();
                        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                        CharSequence text = "Item CLICKED";
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                        toast.show();

                    }
```

it show Item Clicked even when i click on the ImageButton(i setted another function to it), both actions are called...

how can i make it separete the clicks?

But I think the main problem is my .xml, can someone look and see what is wrong, please? I added a lot of relatives, one is for border, another for background, and the third has the items inside =x.

Here's the item_list for the recycler.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:padding="1dp"
        >

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:weightSum="1"


    >

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/thumbnail"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@android:color/white"

        android:layout_marginRight="5dip">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/status"
            android:background="@android:color/white"


            android:layout_width="25dip"
            android:layout_height="25dip"

            />

    </LinearLayout>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titulo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:textColor="#040404"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:background="@android:color/white"



        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/descricao"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:textSize="10dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:background="@android:color/white"



        android:layout_below="@+id/titulo" />



    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"


        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/delete"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/update"
        android:padding="5dip"

        android:onClick="deletarLei" />

    <ImageButton android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/update"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"

        android:padding="5dip"

        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

        />


</RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

When I have similar problems, a tag on the top most ViewGroup in your layout usually solves the problem. In your case this would be the top most ViewGroup in each cell/row.

`android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"`

You can even try setting this on your `RecyclerView`. There are only 3 options, from what I remember `beforeDescendants` should work, otherwise give the other 2 a try.

I think you can just put a `OnClickListener` on the image in your Adapter and just the onItemClickListener on the recycle view. Its not really clear from your code what you're doing.

Comment: i dont get all you said, im trying to do a list with some buttons, if you click on the ImageButton do function A, and if you click in the item on the list(not clicking on the ImageButton) do function B

anyway thanks the answer =)